# How to parse a date from an SSIS Excel filename

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to use the foreach container to iterate through a folder matching something like: "Filename_MMYYYY.xls".  That's easy enough to do; but I can't seem to find a way to parse the MMYYYY from the filename and add it to a variable (or something) that i can use as a lookup field for my DimDate table.  It seems possible with a flat file data source, but not an excel connection.  I'm using Visual Studio 2005.  Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want to take your filename, deconstruct it, and get a date-typed variable out of it?  If so, then you need to start with the filename variable that you get from the Foreach Loop - I'll call that variable @FileName.

First, make a new variable - @FileDate - as a DateTime type.  Go to its properties window (F4), and set the EvaluateAsExpression property to True.  Edit the expression, and type in something like this (you may need to tweak):

(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(@FileName, 12, 4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@FileName, 10, 2) + "-01")

Now, if you want to take that date value and use it in your Data Flow, you can just use it straight in a Derived Column transform, or in an expression on your Lookup SQL statement, or wherever.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see the @FileName variable associated with the Foreach loop.  I can create a variable called fileName, but it's not going to be associated with the actual filename.  I do see system variables like machine name and create time, but no filename.  Maybe I'm just missing something obvious; I'm not at all familiar with SSIS.  This is the first time I'm attempting to use it.

Comment: Create a package level variable @FileName as Todd explained. On the properties tab of your ForEach iterator select the "Variable Mappings" tab. Select your @FileName variable from the list and map it to Index 0. On a file ForEach iterator this will contain the path and file name of the current file.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that index 0 mapped to path and file name.  I also just realized that my derived column had defaulted to a length of 0 which was why my variable was not working correctly.  It is now correctly pulling that data.  Thank you!