# Get the date from Excel File name in a Variable

Tags: excel, ssis

I need to create a SSIS package that would extract data from an Excel source and load it into a SQL Server Destination.

The Excel file name would have a date, typically the file name would look like `emp_20110909.xls` where `11` is the Month, `09` is the Day and `09` is the Year. Now I want to capture this date and in the destination table add another column named "*Extracted_Date*" and populate the captured date for all the records extracted from this excel.

Can anyone tell me how to do that process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a date from an SSIS Excel filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767628/how-to-parse-a-date-from-an-ssis-excel-filename)

Answer (score 2):

Excel as a data source offers no explicit functionality for this whereas the Flat File Source does. I blogged about this under [What is the name of a file](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/05/ssis-what-is-name-of-file.html)

What you're looking to do is have a Foreach File Enumerator look in a folder for your Excel file(s). Assign the value of the currently found file to a variable like `@[User::CurrentFileName]`. That would look something like `C:\ssisdata\mySource\Input\emp_110909.xls`

You would update the Excel Connection Manager to have an expression on the `ExcelFilePath` property so now as the value of @[User::CurrentFileName] changes, so does the actual referenced file. You can find plenty of references to using the foreach enumerator on the web or [search my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965%20felc)

The last bit you need is to parse the value of CurrentFileName to find the year 
(11), month (09) and day (09) elements - or maybe you want it as one big value (110909). For this, I would create 4 variables: FileDate, FileYear, FileMonth, FileDay all as string. Yes, they're numbers but for our usage, treating them as string is going to be easier.

FileDate will correspond to everything between the underscore following emp up until the period of xls. We're going to use the Expression language of SSIS to do this and the particular elements will be [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/substring-ssis-expression), [FINDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression) and [LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/len-ssis-expression)

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::CurrentFileName], FINDSTRING(@[User::CurrentFileName], "emp_", 1) + LEN("emp_"),  6)
```

Here, I was lazy and just "knew" the length was 6 and hardcoded as such. In the event that someone gives us a emp_20110909.xls this will fail. The preceding expression would be modified by finding the position of the period and then calculating the length from the emp_ position.

Now that we know FileDate, we can use SUBSTRING to slice out the first 2 elements for year, next 2 for month and final two for day.

You can then inject those values into your Data Flow via a Derived Task or push into an audit table via Execute SQL Task.

Comment: if you know the file ends with yymmdd.xls then you can left(right(fname,10),6)

Comment: @KeithL Correct, although LEFT didn't exist in SSIS expression language until ... I don't remember. At any rate, point taken

Comment: And this was not to detract anything from your solution.

Comment: Thanks for this responce. could you provide me that all steps with diagramatically plz?